# Is masturbation haram for someone who is in teenage years and lives in North Amercia

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

i’m a teenager and i live in north america where pornography is very common and very watched and most girls are very attractive. I want to know is masturbation allowed in this case since i do not want to get in a haram relationship but my urges are too high. Everytime i prevented myself from masturbation it ended with me watching pornography so i want to know if In my case i can masturbate once a month then clean myself very fast.

Comment: What is haram in Islam can't be made halal especially if the circumstances are not too specific and in that case it would require a fatwa from a well-versed scholar not from a random user on internet platform.

Answer (score 1):

Pornographic material is absolutely forbidden in Islam. We are ordered to lower our gaze and not look at other people's awrah. If however you are looking with desire than even parts which are not awrah are haram to look at. The same applies with the voice of a woman, ordinarily it is not haram to listen to a woman speak but if your intention is lust, this is haram. Be patient brother, it is not worth it. This desire is quick but the devil makes it seem so important to you. Scholars have said that masturbation is not haram if done to alleviate desire and not excessive since this is harmful to your health, because they interpret the ayah which Allah orders us to protect our privates as referring to protecting them from others, not from ourselves, this is the interpretation of SOME scholars. Have modestey and shame brother, this material kills your imaan, if you cannot control your gaze how do you expect to control yourself from haram. The shaytaan comes to you in stages, first it's masturbating, than it's pornography, than what? This life is not worth it, think about the hoor which are promised to believers who have been patient. May Allah grant you forgiveness, guidance, and an understanding and love of His deen. Salam